# Failue while processing glassfish-resources.xml(s) in the archive EAR

Tags: java, glassfish

I'm using glassfish-resources.xml to specify "jdbc-connection-pool" in glassfish4.1.

I'm using EJB + JSF in a maven project under Eclipse.

I put glassfish-resources.xml in "resources/META-INF/" folder (beside persistence.xml).

But when deploying I get this error :

```
Exception during lifecycle processing 
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Failue while processing glassfish-resources.xml(s) in the archive  
-- C:\tools\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\eclipseApps\MyApp-ear\MyApp-web-1.1.24-SNAPSHOT_war\WEB-INF\lib\MyApp-ejb-1.1.24-SNAPSHOT.jarMETA-INF\glassfish-resources.xml (Path not found)
```

Comment: When I parsed the ear file, I found the glassfish-resources.xml in the specified directory... but I don't know why glassfish can't access and parse it.

Comment: As an alternative, the command: $ asadmin add-resources $HOME/glassfish-resources.xml works fine.